# Need to get one value from [object][object]

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12

I have an angular component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hall } from 'src/app/models/hall.model';
import { HallService } from 'src/app/services/hall.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import {City} from "../../models/city.model";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-halls-list',
  templateUrl: './halls-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./halls-list.component.css']
})
export class HallsListComponent implements OnInit {
  Halls?: Hall[];
  currentHall: Hall = {};
  currentIndex = -1;
  name = '';
  placeqty='';
  //cityid='';
    cityid:any;

  constructor(private hallService:HallService,private route: ActivatedRoute,private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.retrieveHalls();

  }

  retrieveHalls(): void {
    this.hallService.getAll()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.Halls = data;
          console.log(data);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }

  refreshList(): void {
    this.retrieveHalls();
    this.currentHall = {};
    this.currentIndex = -1;
  }
  setActiveHall(hall: Hall, index: number): void {
    this.currentHall = hall;
    this.currentIndex = index;
  }

  deleteHall(): void {
    this.hallService.delete(this.currentHall.id)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          console.log(response);
          this.router.navigate(['/halls']);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }
}
```

It is getting data from a rest api that I previously wrote with spring boot. City id is a related column, so it is returning object with a name of a city and it's id. The console output is like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "TestHall",
        "placeqty": 100,
        "cityid": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Dnepr"
        }
    }
]
```

The id of a city and it's name is one. So in this object only one city can be returned. Now what I want is to display city's name but without id. Here is what I have so far in a template:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <h4>Список залов</h4>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li
      class="list-group-item"
      *ngFor="let hall of Halls; let i = index"
      [class.active]="i == currentIndex"
      (click)="setActiveHall(hall, i)"
    >
      {{ hall.name }}
     <br>
     кол-во мест:  {{ hall.placeqty }}
      <br>
     <p>{{hall.cityid | json}}</p>
      <div *ngFor="let item of hall.cityid | keyvalue;">

        {{ item.key}} - {{ item.value }}

      </div>

    </li>

  </ul>

</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div *ngIf="currentHall.id">
    <h4>Зал</h4>
    <div>
      <label><strong>Название:</strong></label> {{ currentHall.name }}
      <label><strong>Количество мест:</strong></label> {{ currentHall.placeqty }}
      <label><strong>Город:</strong></label> {{ currentHall.cityid }}

    </div>


    <a class="badge badge-warning" routerLink="/cities/{{ currentHall.id }}">
      Изменить
    </a>
    <div *ngIf="!currentHall">
      <br />
      <p>Выберите Зал...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If i would use PHP I would do somethin like

```
echo $cityid[0]['name'];
```

without any loop. Is it posible in Angular? Or how I can solve it?

My model class:

```
export class Hall {
  id?:any;
  name?:string;
  placeqty?:string;

  cityid?:string;

}
```

Well. The unswer is very correct. In addition I will add my City model just in case someone will need this. It also worked this way in case of Angular 12, however it is my very first project on Angular and I have no idea how it would work on Angular 11 or lower. But still

```
export class City {
  id?:any;
  name?:string;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to use `{{hall.cityid.name}}` instead of the loop? If that is the case, this has nothing to do with angular really. It's just javascript :) Please check documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: Yes. I even tryed this. But got a compilation error variable is not defined...

Comment: use safe navigation operator, maybe together with an *ngIf, depending on how you want to handle if there is no name... anyways, safe navigation operator will safeguard against null values: `{{ hall.cityid?.name}}` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: I tryed but got this:  Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string'

Comment: Have you in your model declared that cityid is a string? How does your `Hall` model look like?

Comment: I declared it as a string.

Comment: OK, so it isn't a string then... I assume? So it should be a model too. Like `export interface City { name: string; id: number; }` and your `Hall` model should declare it like `cityid: City`. Your model needs to match the data you are getting, otherwise your IDE will correctly tell you that you are doing something you are not supposed to ;)

Comment: Greate thank you all. Basicly it reminds ne how it was done in Java. There is also a same construction present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To gather all comments to an answer instead...

So if you are receiving data like:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "TestHall",
    "placeqty": 100,
    "cityid": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Dnepr"
    }
}
```

Your models need to first of all match, so they should be something like this:

```
interface Hall {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  placeqty: number;
  cityid: City;
}

interface City {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

Now, for nested objects, you can use the safe navigation operator to safeguard `null` or `undefined` values. And to get the name of the city you just access that nested property with:

```
<p>{{ hall.cityid?.name }}</p>
```